# BLTouch homing correct, but nozzle hits bed during print

Tags: z-axis, bltouch, creality-ender-5, z-probe

So I have this exact problem as in this thread: [BLTouch calibrated, nozzle still dives into the bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11007/bltouch-calibrated-nozzle-still-dives-into-the-bed)

But I don't see a clear solution to that question, or I don't understand. After correct calibration of the BLTouch, it is homing correct with the correct nozzle distance to bed, but when printing it hits the bed. It's supposed to be plug & play ;).

Here are the details of my setup:

- Ender 5 with 4.2.7 silent board
- TH3D Marlin 2.0 firmware (flashed it and then an EEPROM reset)
- Cura slicer 4.10.0
- BLTouch V3 from Trianglelab mounted on 5-pin, but end-stop on the micro-switch end-stop 2-pin. Also enabled this in Marlin. Offset -41, -11, 0

Could someone please help me? But be aware I'm quite new in programming stuff.

Comment: Did you set a Z-offset? (E.g. using the display menu to define it, or `M851 Zx.xx` if done over USB) Not the sensor mounting offset.

Comment: Try setting Z-offset correctly in configuration menu on Ender 5 display. If you double-click main button while printing you should have option to calibrate offset while printing, but it will only work for current print. So after this you have to use gained values in configuration menu and set Z-offset. This double-click function is called "Babystep Z".

Comment: Hi, I adjusted the nozzle height via Motion - Move axis -Move Z. Wrote down the distance. And then I set the correct distance with Z offet/babystep and saved it.  Off topic:  I do not get an email when there is a reply. Any idea how to set this?

Comment: Hi, damn just figured out what I did wrong. Or what the guy in de video did wrong. He said to adjust the z axis until the correct clearance. Note down the number and fill this in babystep. Now I watched a different video and he said to first set the z to '0' and then go to Zoffset/babystep and adjust the nozzle to the correct height. And that worked for me! Thanks guys for helping me out too! Appreciate it!

Comment: @user35400 Great that you found the culprit! But, please do not post answers in comments, post an answer below in the "answer section". This is a Q/A format website, questions deserve answers of which the best is voted on top. This way, for other people with the same question, they immediately see if there is a voted or accepted answer. Votes on questions and answers give you reputation which gives you [privileges](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Beware that comments are for requesting info to the poster of the question or the answer and may be deleted after time. Thanks

Comment: @0scar. You mean I have to edit my question and paste my solution under that post?

Comment: @user35400 SE sites are Q and A sites, so the question can be answered by others (or yourself) in the"Your Answer" section below. Comments are for other to comment on the Q and A's to ask for more details.